# "Success: Test not run" in Test Sessions window (Resharper) in Visual Studio

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I use Resharper in Visual Studio 2015 for running tests. However I'm confused with the statuses `Test not run` - they are there for both Success and Failed. If I run one of such tests separately, the status temporary changes to `Pending: Test not run` and then back to `Success: Test not run`. I can't find any info why the test hasn't run. Furthermore I don't understand why the status is Success (or Failed) if the test was not run - how could it know?

How should I interpret the statuses and what can I do to make it run all tests?

(Using VS 2015 Enterprise with Update 1, Resharper Ultimate 10.0.2, both up-to-date to the moment, test framework is MsTest)

[image]

Comment: what unit test framework?

Answer (score 5):

I was suffering the same "Test not run" message. I believe that it might be related to running the unit tests with coverage and then adding more unit tests and running them without coverage.

I cleared it in my environment by creating a 'new session' (right click the root unit test and select from the context menu, or Ctrl+U,N) and running all the unit tests. I also closed the original session without saving the results.

I tried to characterise the issue of "Test not run" without success. If you can confirm if deleting the unit test session solves it, that would be good to know.

(Also using the latest VS2015 and R#)

Edit:

I managed to reproduce the "Test not run" by clearing a test result in my unit test suite, then running that test in debug with a breakpoint and terminating the debug session. Running all the tests now reports "Success: Test not run" even though the debugged test has now run through to completion.

(This is using R# menu | unit tests | run all tests from solution. The VS2015 Test Explorer display doesn't show the same test not run issue)

The easier method to clear the status is to right click it and choose Clear Test Result before running all the tests again

Comment: Agreed - just reproduced this behaviour with Resharper Ultimate 10.0.2.  That was really annoying me, but at least there's a workaround.

Comment: Still happening with VS2017 & R# 2018.1.3. 

After debugging a unit test I started to see loads of "Element {test name} was left pending after its run completion", with a status "Success: Test not run". Closing the unit test session and starting a new one solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This old issue has either reappeared or never been fixed (ReSharper 2022.2.4), and closing and opening a new test session, as some answers and comments suggest, also does not help.

I would consider this a bug in ReSharper, simply because this behavior is unintuitive and poorly or not at all explained in the UI or documentation, and this alone is a reason why I would recommend everyone seeing this to just submit a bug report.